# Markdown center bulletpoint (inside HTML block)

Tags: html, markdown

I'm editing a markdown file (on GitHub), where I include a bulleted list, each list has the bulleted text and a picture, both aligned to the center. I used HTML divs for centering:

```markdown
<div align="center">
  * Time-and-place network:<br>
  <img src="https://github.com/me9hanics/ArtProject/assets/82604073/7690b7fc-b46e-4e27-ae98-7aa8bc046dc5" width=80% alt="Time-and-place network" >
</div>
```

This centers the text, but the bullet point itself does not get centered, it stays on the left.
How could I fix this? It's not important to center with HTML blocks, but I found it convenient.

Comment: Note that the `align` attribute has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) for 20 years or more.